# Regex replace all occurrences of text WITH brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

In short i need to replace every occurrence of text betweeen brackets including the brackets in a string, and the text to be replaced will be in a variable in Javascript.
A simple regex in a replace method wont work because of the brackets.

Example, replace "[test] [teste] test [hello]" with a variable with the value of "hi".
Output: "hi hi test [hello]"

Comment: So you're replacing the text "[test]" but not "test". You're confusing yourself by thinking of brackets as special. Just replace "[test]" with "hi"..

Answer (score 1):

```
"[test] [teste] test".replace(/\[.*?\]/g, 'hi')
```

escape the brackets with "\" and use g flag

edit: removed the i flag and chnaged w to . to handle anything inside brackets

Comment: The case insensitive flag is redundant.

Comment: Thats correct for provided examples but I beleive that @yuribsl can have something else inside brackets

Comment: But i cant replace every occurrence of text between brackets, for example replacing "[test]" for "hi" in the string "[test] [test] test [hello]" would become "hi hi test [hello]"

Comment: with the above regex i got this: 
var text = "[test] [test] test [hello]"
text.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, 'hi')
Output: "hi hi test hi"

Comment: Yes and that's how I understood your question, so can you please elaborate what you really want?

Comment: If you want to replace only specific text, then please change the .*? in the replace with your desired string:

Comment: Sorry for the english lol, for example, i will have a variable in JS with the value of "[test]", then in a string i need to replace every occurrence of "[test]". "test" ( the value between the brackets) is dynamic, later on i can have "[newvalue]", then i need to use the same regex to replace every occurrence of "[newvalue]".

Comment: but how can i set a js variable to a regex expression?

Comment: Then you need to do it with regex constructor and user variable with template literals. Please look for that.

Comment: i need to replace an exact string, if i want to replace "[test]"  "[test] [test] test [hello]" could become "hi hi test [hello]" or "dude dude test [hello]"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for but .match will store off the matches in an array and .replace will perform the replace for you.

```js
const regex = /\[.*?\]/g;

var mutable = "[test] [teste] test";
const matches = mutable.match(regex); // Save all matches to an array
mutable = mutable.replace(regex, 'dude'); // Replace matches

console.log(mutable);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the way i found to do it was to get my variable to be replaced, example:
var test= "[test]",
Then i replaced the brackets in it so it would become "\[test\]", then i used:

```
var regex = new RegExp(test+"+","gm")
```

then i used this regex in JS replace method.